# Trying to do an API call on discord.js, keep getting await errors

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Im trying to call upon crypto currencies and print out the current price using a discord command. My next step is to add a command like !btc 50 which should print out 50$ worth of bitcoin into an bitcoin amount. For example: 50$ = 0.0004523BTC.

Im struggling getting the current price and have no idea if I'm even on the right track.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const axios = require('axios');


const token = '-';
const PREFIX ='!';
var btcaddy = "-";

//1. Import coingecko-api
const CoinGecko = require('coingecko-api');

//2. Initiate the CoinGecko API Client
const CoinGeckoClient = new CoinGecko();

//3. Make calls
var func = async() => {
  let data = await CoinGeckoClient.ping();
  
}
let data = await CoinGeckoClient.coins.fetch('bitcoin', {});
    client.on('message', message=>{
        let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

        switch(args[0]){
            case 'btc':
                const btc = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle ('Thank you for choosing us!')
                .addField ('Bitcoin address', `${btcaddy}`)
                .addField ('Bitcoin address', `${data}`)
                .setColor (0x0099FF)
                message.channel.send(btc);
            break;


        }
    })
    
client.login(token);
```

Comment: can you show us the error message?

Comment: You're definitely gonna have an error when you try to use the await keyword at the top of your file here: `let data = await CoinGeckoClient.coins.fetch`. Start by moving that into the `client.on("message")` event listener and making the function in the event listener async

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?